# How does git decide when there are merge conflicts?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a question about how git works for a certain case. These are the steps, and assume these are the only changes done to the repo:

1. initially I have branch master
2. I create a new branch "feature-1" off of master
3. I add several commits to "feature-1" branch
4. I create a new branch "feature-2" off of "feature-1"
5. I add several commits to "feature-2" branch
6. I merge "feature-1" branch into master  -
7. I add several more commits to this "feature-2" branch

Now, when I want to merge "feature-2" into "master", I expect not to have any conflits, because all the commits that are merged into "master" from "feature-1" branch are already in "feature-2" branch. So "feature-2" should be no different than a branch created off of "master" after step 6

However, when I want to merge "feature-2" into "master", I get merge conflicts, git thinking all changes done in "feature-1" conflict with what's in "feature-2", whereas they come from exactly the same commits,  and

commits in "feature-2" = (all commits in "feature-1") + some more commits.

What's causing git into thinking there are conflicts in this case? And maybe in general, how does git decide when there are merge confclits?

Comment: Are there new commits on `master` after `feature-1` has been merged into it? They are the source of conflicts.

Comment: No, no new commits. But there is a merge commit iwhen feature-1 is merged into master. Maybe that could be the cause as Duperez  pointed out below?

Comment: Conflicts occur when the comparison of the *merge base* commit to each of the two *tip* commits shows (a) the same file changed, and (b) the same, or "touching" (abutting), lines changed within that file. They can also occur due to high-level changes, e.g., if base vs branch tip #1 says to rename file A to ABC, and base vs branch tip #2 says to rename file A to XYZ. Which name should Git use? It doesn't know.

Comment: What this means is that to understand where the conflict came from, you must look at the *merge base* version of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things you need to now to get whow git works for conflicts:

1. Actually git uses the commits to check if branchs are equals or not.
2. All changes are commits in someway (merges are in it too)

Knowing that things, let check your example again.

lets suppose that master is like tat:
Branch: **master**
Commits: *Commit-A*

And than you create feature-1 and commit one thing. It will be like that:
Branch: **feature-1**
Commits: *Commit-A* (From master), *Commit-B*

From feature-1 you create feature-2 and commit another thing. It will be like that:
Branch: **feature-2**
Commits: *Commit-A* (From master), *Commit-B* (From feature-1), *Commit-C*

Now, you merge Feature-1 into master, lets check master again:
Branch: **master**
Commits: *Commit-A*, *Commit-B* (From feature-1), *Commit-D* (commit created by merge)

Can you see that the "merge commit" that exists in master do not exists in Feature-2 even Feature-2 already have the code? the merged branch branch may have the "merge information" to be merged into master, even it do not make difference in the code.

Comment: Hmm yeah I was suspecting the merge commit as well. So that's probably the cause then right?

Comment: Yep, That's the only thing I can think of as the cause of the problem

Comment: this does not point to the actual problem. If the merge `feature1 -> master` did not introduce any new change (e.g : if the content of the merge commit is exactly the same as the content of `feature1`), and `feature2` was really based on the last commit of `feature1`, then there should be no conflict when, even though `Commit-D` exists.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a diagram of what you describe :

```
*--b--e1--e2--e3---m <- master
    \             /
     *--*--*--*--f1--*--*--*--f2 <- feature2
                 ^
             feature1
```

---

When merging `feature2` with master, `git` will use commit `f1` as the "merge base", and will try to combine the diff `f1..m` with the diff `f1..f2`.

Commit `m` includes modifications brought by the extra commits on `master` -- I named them `e1 e2 e3` on the diagram.

From what you describe, there were no conflicts when merging `feature1` with these modifications.

But there can still be some conflicts between these modifications (which will appear in `f1..m`) and the modifications in `feature2`.

---

In your comment, you gave additional details : you claim your history is actually :

```
# no other commits on master while feature1 was branched :
*--b---------------m <- master
    \             /
     *--*--*--*--f1--*--*--*--f2 <- feature2
                 ^
             feature1
```

If this were the case, then merging `feature2` into `master` should not trigger any conflict.

You can take a closer look at the history of your three branches :

```
git log --oneline --graph master feature1 feature2
```

Some possible deviations could be :

- another feature was merged into `master` between `b` and `m`
- there were some more commits on `master` *after* `m`
- somme commits on `feature1` were actually rebased or amended before being merged into `master` :

  ```
  *--b---------------m <- master
      \             /
       *--*--*--y--y <- feature1
              \
               x--x--*--*--*--f2 <- feature2

   # if commits "y--y" are rewritten version of "x--x", there will probably
   # be a conflict when combining the diff "y--y" with the diff "x--x"
  ```

Comment: In my case, there are no commits e1, e2, e3. Thats what I mean by "assume these are the only changes done to the repo" in the question. Only commits are the ones I mentioned in the steps, so no commits done on master between creation of f1 and merging of f1.

Comment: Hmmm that's odd. Does `git diff f1 m` show any difference ?